# dpkg, apt-get: Executing post-install steps hangs

Tags: 16.04, apt, dpkg

Whenever I try to use `dpkg` or `apt-get`, it always hangs on post-install step and stays forever. 
Example when installing oracle: (but happens with others apps too)
[image: hanging while installing oracle]

Any suggestions to log or debug why this happens?

Comment: This might seem like a redundant, or 'dumb', question; but have you installed all of the libraries, or/and did you have an internet connection to check for the dependencies as you were installing the .dpkg? 

I've installed Oracle11gR2 enterprise edition on 12.04 through 16.04 and there has been about (3/4)*1Gb of dependencies. For instance: quite few of the different versions of the C++ libs, and unix-odbc.

Comment: pretty qood question I'd say, but I chose to install all updates while installing Ubuntu. Can you please tell how I explicitly can force to install this dependencies?

Comment: No, you would have to do far more than that. Do you have a list of the dependencies? With in the Oracle database documentation for the installation, and through many sources online you should have something like this:

Answer (score 0):

THERE WAS NO WAY I WAS ABOUT TO MAKE MULTIPLE COMMENTS!

No, you would have to do far more than that. Do you have a list of the dependencies? With in the Oracle database documentation for the installation, and through many sources online you should have something like this:

`:~$ sudo bash`

`:~# apt-get -y install alien`

`:~# apt-get -y install autoconf`

`:~# apt-get -y install automake`

`:~# apt-get -y install autotools-dev`

`:~# apt-get -y install binutils`

`:~# apt-get -y install bzip2`

`:~# apt-get -y install doxygen`

`:~# apt-get -y install elfutils`

`:~# apt-get -y install expat`

`:~# apt-get -y install gawk`

`:~# apt-get -y install gcc`

`:~# apt-get -y install gcc-multilib`

`:~# apt-get -y install g++-multilib`

## NOTE: You will have to drop into the Precise Pangolin repository in order to find the ia32-libs, and considering you didn't do that immediately it could break your system.

`:~# apt-get -y install ia32-libs`

`:~# apt-get -y install ksh`

`:~# apt-get -y install less`

`:~# apt-get -y install lesstif2`

`:~# apt-get -y install lesstif2-dev`

`:~# apt-get -y install lib32z1`

`:~# apt-get -y install libaio1`

`:~# apt-get -y install libaio-dev`

`:~# apt-get -y install libc6-dev`

`:~# apt-get -y install libc6-dev-i386`

`:~# apt-get -y install libc6-i386`

`:~# apt-get -y install libelf-dev`

`:~# apt-get -y install libltdl-dev`

`:~# apt-get -y install libmotif4`

`:~# apt-get -y install libodbcinstq4-1 libodbcinstq4-1:i386`

`:~# apt-get -y nstall libpth-dev`

`:~# apt-get -y install libpthread-stubs0`

`:~# apt-get -y install libpthread-stubs0-dev`

`:~# apt-get -y install libstdc++5`

`:~# apt-get -y install lsb-cxx`

`:~# apt-get -y install make`

`:~# apt-get -y install openssh-server`

`:~# apt-get -y install pdksh`

`:~# apt-get -y install rlwrap`

`:~# apt-get -y install rpm`

`:~# apt-get -y install sysstat`

`:~# apt-get -y install unixodbc`

`:~# apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev`

`:~# apt-get -y install unzip`

`:~# apt-get -y install x11-utils`

`:~# apt-get -y install zlibc`

Comment: what about possible issues with partitions, disks etc; I tried 14.04 on laptop - the same thing, but on VM it works